# C++ конкатенация строк strcat - crash программы

Tags: c++

Почему данный код вызывает падение программы (отличается только наличием %s символа)

```
char test1[2048]="";
strcat(test1,"Какой-то то текст %s\n");
```

данный код ошибок не вызывает

```
сhar test1[2048]="";
strcat(test1,"Какой-то то текст \n");
```

компилятор - mingw64

Comment: Падение на этом вызове? или дальше идет что-то типа `printf(test1);`?

Comment: падение происходит именно на strcat до printf не доходит.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Включив режим телепатии и ясновидения :), думаю, что в программе на самом деле этим дело не заканчивается, и дальше идет что-то вроде

```
char test1[2048]="";
strcat(test1,"Какой-то то текст %s\n");
printf(test1);
```

И вот тут оно и сыпется, пытаясь обратиться к какой-то случайной памяти из-за наличия `%s`, для которого не передан аргумент.
Если хотите посмотреть, что в строке `test1` - выводите ее или с помощью `puts()`, или `printf("%s\n",test1);`.

Comment: char test1[2048]="";
strcat(test1,"Какой-то то текст %s\n");
далее в коде printf(test1,"какой-то текст2");

Comment: если strcat исправить на strcat_s то программа не падает, падение происходит именно на strcat.

Comment: Дайте [минимальный воспроизводящий проблему код](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - без этого говорить не о чем...